# Sadhana Bakthi and Bakthi Yoga

Tags: yoga, bhakti

There are types of Bakthis. What is Sadhana Bakthi? Will this come under Bakthi Yoga?

Comment: Here is some info about types of bhakti (not a comprehensive list). http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/what-is-the-navavidha-bhakti/7298#7298. Yes Sadhana Bhakti as I understand it, is a practical application of bhakti yoga. You may want to clarify in your question where you read about sadhana bhakti, just so users are clear where you're getting the information for it.

Comment: I read in Mahabaratha about sadana bakthi.