# How do I remember "ब्रह्म"(Brahman) while working in office?

Tags: brahman

I have always been taught that one should offer all his work to "ब्रह्म" (Supreme God), which seem to be very difficult while working in office.
I have been trying to remain conscious about what I do, but it's very difficult, and after a couple of days,

What are the methods one can use to remember God while performing daily life activities?

For e.g. When ever I go for lunch, I try to remain conscious.

Comment: I thought its Hinduism stackexchange, bharam is god

Comment: "How do I remember bharam while working in office?" What is bharam? I don't know that word. Can you explain it in the question?

Comment: @Tezz you are right tezz

Comment: You keep repeating any name of God silently.

Comment: Near to impossible either you will mess-up your work or you will not be able to concentrate. You can only rembember bramhan or work at a time. I think you should learn from the Bhagwad Gita episode, BG was taught just before the commencement of war. In your case war is office work, act similarly before getting into action, remember Bramhan, and just be conscious that what you do is for appeasement of Bramhan karma yoga(phala tyaga), then start your work in karma yoga(that way you would not be attributed to any karma you can burn your leftover karma by chanting rama nama later).

Comment: @Rishi You can just meditate on the thing that "The whole universe is Brahman." / "Sarva Khalvidam Brahman."...so you can tay to see things of office as also Brahman.. whole Universe is manifestation of Brahman.. My answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11529/i-want-scripture-based-explanation-for-god-is-everywhere/15705#15705) also may help you!

Comment: @Yogi The perception you have is not bad, but practically I have enough time to remember the source of creation or self.
Here are some points I have discovered in Books:
**1:** Breathe as if you become with the nature
**2:** In mind try to bow down to everything, will give you access to inner dimensions.
**3:** Try to Keep your spine straight, you will feel more aware.
**4:** Every hour remind your self you will fall dead one day.
**5:** Walk in straight lines, every gestures do it consciously
**6:** Also think you are alone on this world.
**7:** Do yajna daily, it is very powerful

Comment: All these points may help one to access spiritual dimensions easily, Well they are working for me.:)

Comment: @Rishi In this highest state of supreme God consciousness [anuttara] there is no need of spiritual progress, no contemplation, no art of expression, no investigation, no meditation, no concentration, no recitation, exertion or practice. Tell me then, what is the supreme and well-ascertained truth? Listen indeed to this! Neither abandon nor accept anything, enjoy everything, remain as you are!

Comment: @Rishi it's not possible for a human to do 2 things at the same time. You will mess up your work if you try to do 2 things at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Srimad Bhāgavataṃ [7.5.23-24](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/5/23-24), Prahlada says there are nine ways of worshipping the Lord. They are famously known as the Navavidha bhakti margas.

śrī-prahlāda uvāca

> **śravaṇaṁ kīrtanaṁ viṣṇoḥ
>
>   smaraṇaṁ pāda-sevanam
>
>   arcanaṁ vandanaṁ dāsyaṁ
>
>   sakhyam ātma-nivedanam**
>
> **iti puṁsārpitā viṣṇau
>
>   bhaktiś cen nava-lakṣaṇā
>
>   kriyeta bhagavaty addhā
>
>   tan manye ’dhītam uttamam**
>
> Translation : Prahlāda Mahārāja said: Hearing and chanting about the transcendental holy name, form, qualities, paraphernalia and pastimes of Lord Viṣṇu, remembering them, serving the lotus feet of the Lord, offering the Lord respectful worship with sixteen types of paraphernalia, offering prayers to the Lord, becoming His servant, considering the Lord one’s best friend, and surrendering everything unto Him (in other words, serving Him with the body, mind and words) — these nine processes are accepted as pure devotional service. One who has dedicated his life to the service of Viṣṇu through these nine methods should be understood to be the most learned person, for he has acquired complete knowledge.

**The nine forms of devotion are**:

- Shravanam – Hearing the names and glories of the Lord
- Keertanam – Chanting His glories
- Smaranam – Remembering the Lord
- Pāda sevanam – Serving the Lord’s feet
- Archanam      – Worshiping the Lord
- Vandanam – Offering obeisance unto the Lord
- Dāsyaṃ – Serving the Lord as His servant
- Sakhyam – Developing friendship with the Lord
- ātma Nivedanaṃ – Total surrender of oneself to the Lord

Even though the paths are different, they all lead to the same destination.

But from the above list Dāsyaṃ, sakhyam, ātmanivedanaṃ are practically not possible for normal human beings like us. So, the best ways one can easily follow are :

***Shravanam***

Hearing the glories, songs, bhajans of the Lord whenever possible.

***Keerthanam***

Singing or chanting the Lord's name and glories.

***Smaranam***

The easiest way possible. Remembering the name of the Lord whenever possible.

***Vandanam***

Prostrating before the lord. Offering obeisances to the Lord.

These are the easiest ways you can remember the Lord whatever you are doing.

Before having food, offering it to the Lord as gratitude also helps in developing devotion in one's heart. You can learn more about devotion from [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/what-is-the-navavidha-bhakti/7298?s=2|0.1079#7298) answer.

In one statement: You can chant or remember the name of the Lord while you are performing any other daily life activity (say while you are in office or having lunch).

Comment: +1 for this, but what about the last three steps, kindly explain them aswell

Comment: @Rishi See [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/what-is-the-navavidha-bhakti/7298#7298) answer.  All the nine forms are explained there.