# Some daily-life hacks to always keep remembrance of God / Isht Devta or Devi

Tags: worship, life

Life has lots of challenges, ups and downs. It is very easy to forget your Isht Devi/Devta (God), while enganged in worldly activities.

What are some life hacks to stay connected to God, while performing our daily duties in this mrityu loka (world) ?

EDIT: While there is a question asked about [methods of remembering God](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17053/how-do-i-remember-%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AEbrahman-while-working-in-office#17053) for an office-going person, my question is neither for an employee in office, nor is it about simply methods.
Life-hacks means ways in which we tactically engage our mind to transform a real world feeling into bhagvad-feeling.

One example that comes to my mind is when we say Ram Ram (as a salutation) to a friend. I have heard that the reason for saying it twice is to remember that the God that resides in me, is the same God that resides in the person I am meeting.
This consciousness is a kind of hack that helps a devotee keep connected to God.

Comment: Related or possible duplicate of [how can one increase bhakti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22526/6981)

Comment: you answered your own question - life has ups and downs. think of God during ups and downs.  at least the downs. Kunti devi specifically requests Krishna for continuous problems in life so that she can remember and call to him for help. For many people, remembering God is a way/excuse to get out of their worldly problems. For Kunti, getting out of worldly problems is a way/excuse to remember him.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i remember "ब्रह्म"(Brahman) while working in office?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17053/how-do-i-remember-%e0%a4%ac%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%b9%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%aebrahman-while-working-in-office)

Comment: @Sarvabhouma it wouldn't be good to close this question as a duplicate of that one, unless this question is also off-topic, because then no answer can be given. Is this question off-topic?

Comment: @Zanna Both the questions are not off-topic. I have cast my reopen vote on that question. It doesn't ask for a personal help. It is general question how to remember god while doing daily activities.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, I have edited (expanded) my question to explain how it is different.

Comment: Close your eyes for 30 secs and remember god. Instant energy :)